# Power BI line chart over Date/Time on Axis

Tags: date, time, powerbi, hierarchy, linechart

I need to create a line chart with time line on Axis and display the Date hierarchy ( day, month, quarter, year ) each in separate line below the axis representation. All the telemetry data is in continuous 10 min span range on the same calendar day and hour.  I've two separate fields representing the time only and date. I tried drill down option but not able to achieve that. could you please help me in this regard?

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking. Can you improve your question? Data sample, model diagram, dax formulas, desired result mockup would be helpful.

Comment: I have a some how similar requirement, did you get a solution to this?

Comment: I've not been able to find a solution to this issue. I just used Power BI in a small project for a short period.